# Two linked lookupEdit in devExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl winform and c#

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a problem. For example;

**gridControl at 3.columns 5.cells in lookUpEdit datasource binding** or dynamically 1.columns 5.cells,2.columns 5.cells ... in lookUpEdit datasource binding.

- datasource: firebird or sqlServer(dataset)
- components: devExpress gridControl gridView

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you share some code? To better understand the problem.

Comment: This is your setup. What's the problem with that?

Comment: How to bind to the data source of the lookupEdit(RepositoryItemLookUpEdit) in the selected cell in gridView?

Comment: I have no code :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you should use the approach demonstrated in the [How to filter a second LookUp column based on a first LookUp column's value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A237/how-to-filter-a-second-lookup-column-based-on-a-first-lookup-column-s-value)) knowledge base article:

```
void gridView1_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ColumnView view = (ColumnView)sender;
    if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "CityCode" && view.ActiveEditor is LookUpEdit) {
        LookUpEdit edit = (LookUpEdit)view.ActiveEditor;
        string countryCode = (string)view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("CountryCode");
        edit.Properties.DataSource = GetFilteredCities(countryCode);
    }
}
```

Refer to the [How to filter a second LookUp column based on a first LookUp column's value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E898/how-to-filter-a-second-lookup-column-based-on-a-first-lookup-column-s-value) example, where this approach is shown in action.